# Retrieving multiple matches of a string (upto certain length) using regex

Tags: regex, vb.net

I am using VB 2010 where I want to extract multiple matches out of a string with up to certain length. Fo example if the string is:

> REQ:     [COL03-DO178BCReqB-7496358][COL03-DO178BCReqB-7495784]# this whole line is a string where match has to be performed
>   [COL03-DO178BCReqB-7495782][COL03-DO178BCReqB-7495778]

I want to extract all the matches starting with "COL03-DO178BCReqB-" and upto 25 characters from start such that the output of the matches should be:

COL03-DO178BCReqB-7496358

COL03-DO178BCReqB-7495784

COL03-DO178BCReqB-7495782

COL03-DO178BCReqB-7495778

I wanted to know what pattern should I give while using `Regex.Matches`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(COL03-DO178BCReqB-.{7})
```

you can try it here: https://regex101.com/r/GYBfF9/3

since "COL03-DO178BCReqB-" has 18 characters, we only need to match 7 more. with ".", every character is matched and with {7} we are telling it to match it 7 times.

Comment: Thank you so much, but it seems like you thought the match should end at occurrence of "]" character. However, this is not what I wanted. I wanted to end the match at exactly 25 characters from the start of "COL03-DO178BCReqB-". Can that be done? can we mention the 25 character length somewhere?

For eg, if the string is: REQ: COL03-DO178BCReqB-7496358 hwqb dhu COL03-DO178BCReqB-7495784 wjk fwuh this whole line is a string where match has to be performed [COL03-DO178BCReqB-7495782][COL03-DO178BCReqB-7495778]

Comment: oh you mean like this? (COL03-DO178BCReqB-.{7}) I took the first 18 characters into account and added the 7 additional characters

Comment: Thank you so much!!